# Retrieving data from UID.Push()

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve data from getUID.push() on Firebase DataBase I would like get all data under push() like name, status and age?
Can you help me? here is my database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRBY2.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I put a image on my question , can you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have implemented Firebase authentication and `Adultos` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to get those keys, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Adultos").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Te output in your logcat will be all those pushed ids highlighted in red.

Comment: Can i use that on my RecyclerView? Because i want get data from push and list that

Comment: Yes you can. **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i will follow all your steps and return your post.

Comment: So , i follow all steps but my recycleView empty now

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time. Have you got the ids using my above code?

Comment: The issue regarding the `RecyclerView` is basically another question that I cannot answer in a comment and without the necessary code and in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.